# Correct regex for matching the string with max number value

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a way to match all the strings using regular expressions like below

Input String:

```
    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_500.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_400.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_250.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_10.txt

    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_640.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_1280.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_540.txt

    https://subdomain.domain.com/adfd386be957c3247/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto3_250.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/adfd386be957c3247/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto3_100.txt

    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_640.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_540.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_980.csv
```

Expected Output:

```
    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_500.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_1280.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/adfd386be957c3247/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto3_250.txt
    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_980.csv
```

I am trying the below expression, but it is getting all the urls, how can I limit the results to only what I want?

```
    "https://subdomain.domain.com/([^,:"]+?([_\d]*?)).(txt|csv)"
```

Comment: If the only differences are the numbers at the end, then try `https://subdomain\.domain\.com/[^,:"]+(?:500|1280|980)\.(?:txt|csv)` https://regex101.com/r/bEp9H1/1

Comment: Can you explain, what criteria you use to filter? I can write regex `980\.csv$|((25|50|128)0\.txt)$` and it will filter your input as you want

Comment: Regex syntax differs depending on the language. How can you guys answer without knowing the language that he is using? I think it is python, but I am not sure.

Comment: What you want is outside of the capabilities for regexes. Use the pragramming language to group the results by the first capture group and then extract the maximum value by the second capture group.

Comment: Did you say what you want ? I didn't see that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your blocks are indeed grouped as in your question, it is easy to do this
using a regex.

`@"(?m)(?:^[^\S\r\n]*(https?://\S+?_)(\d+)\.(txt|csv)[^\S\r\n]*$\r?\n)+(?=\s*\r\n|$)"`

Explained

```
 (?m)
 (?:                           # Cluster group for block
      ^                             # BOL
      [^\S\r\n]*                    # Optional horizontal whitespace
      ( https?:// \S+? _ )          # (1), Location
      ( \d+ )                       # (2), Number
      \. 
      ( txt | csv )                 # (3), Extension
      [^\S\r\n]*                    # Optional horizontal whitespace
      $ \r? \n                      # EOL plus linebreak
 )+                            # End cluster, 1 to many times
 (?= \s* \r \n | $ )           # Lookahead to determine where the end of block is
```

C# code sample

```
var str =
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_500.txt\n" + 
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_400.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_250.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_10.txt\n" +
"\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_640.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_1280.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_540.txt\n" +
"\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/adfd386be957c3247/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto3_250.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/adfd386be957c3247/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto3_100.txt\n" +
"\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_640.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_540.txt\n" +
"    https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_980.csv\n" +
"\n";

// This regex matches a block each time
var RxBlock = new Regex(@"(?m)(?:^[^\S\r\n]*(https?://\S+?_)(\d+)\.(txt|csv)[^\S\r\n]*$\r?\n)+(?=\s*\r\n|$)");

Match M = RxBlock.Match(str);
while (M.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection ccFileLoc = M.Groups[1].Captures;  // location
    CaptureCollection ccFileNum = M.Groups[2].Captures;  // number
    CaptureCollection ccFileExt = M.Groups[3].Captures;  // extension

    String Loc = ccFileLoc[0].Value;
    String Ext = ccFileExt[0].Value;
    int Largest = 0;
    bool bValid = true;

    if (Int32.TryParse(ccFileNum[0].Value, out Largest))
    {
        int cur_num = 0;
        int cnt = ccFileLoc.Count;

        for (int i = 0; bValid && i < cnt; i++)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(ccFileNum[i].Value, out cur_num) || ccFileLoc[i].Value != Loc)
                bValid = false;
            else
            if (cur_num > Largest)
            {
                Largest = cur_num;
                Ext = ccFileExt[i].Value;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        bValid = false;

    if ( bValid )
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}.{2} ", Loc, Largest, Ext);

    M = M.NextMatch();
}
```

Output

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/e8cf09b4763e03d208dfd21121baacd4/domain_p6amv8xJVr1qto1_500.txt
https://subdomain.domain.com/163c7b0508062729dsdk1f1e264210/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto2_1280.txt
https://subdomain.domain.com/adfd386be957c3247/domain_p6amv8xJVr1wvilqto3_250.txt
https://subdomain.domain.com/25e5ccd5e95ca2888a39b939f199b822/domain_p6amv8xJVr1ilqto4_980.csv
```

---

Even if your data is not sorted, you could still use regex this way.
It has to have a line sort done on it first.
Then, it needs a slight modification. If you want to do it this
way, let me know and I might show you how.

Comment: That'a a detailed and wonderfully explained. Thanks for the efforts, It helped me to solve the problem in multiple ways. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the negated character class `[^,:"]+` to not match a comma, colon or double quote. I don't think you have to make it non greedy using the `?`

Then match 1+ digits followed by an underscore and any of the listed numbers `(?:500|1280|980)` using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Instead of matching 0+ times an underscore or digit non greedy `[_\d]*?`, for your example data, you could also match 1+ digits followed by an underscore `\d+_`

Note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

```
https://subdomain\.domain\.com/[^,:"]+\d+_(?:500|1280|980)\.(?:txt|csv)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdbYCm/1)

Answer (score 0):

As I learned it is almost impossible to achieve such a thing using Regex, I've implemented this in C# using LINQ without regex. Thanks to Burdui, I came up with this while trying on your suggestion.

```
    public List<string> FindUnique(List<string> Urls)
    {
        var distinct = Urls.Distinct();
        var grouping = distinct.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(1, x.LastIndexOf('_')));

        if (grouping.Count() > 0)
        { 
            return grouping.Select(x =>
                x.First(a =>
                    a.Contains(x.Max(y =>
                        Int32.Parse(y.Substring(y.LastIndexOf('_') + 1).Split('.')[0])).ToString())
                )
            ).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return distinct.ToList();
        }
    }
```